# HTML CSS Hover Image Link with One Image

Tags: html, css

User Alois Madhal posted an awesome piece of advice for someone trying to create a hover image.  I would like to use this same technique but as an image link.  Is it possible?  I've tried all sorts of ways but think I must be missing something obvious.  Here is the info Alois provided:

```
 <style>
    #tuxie {
        width: 25px; height: 25px;
        background: url('images/tuxie.png') no-repeat left top;
    }
    #tuxie:hover { background-position: -25px 0px }
</style>

<div id="tuxie" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.

All you need to do is use `<a href="...">` as you normally would for a link.

The important thing is to add `display:inline-block` to the link's styles. This will allow you to apply width and height to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the display part!  That did the trick, thank you so very much!!